# How to send new size of array from C++ DLL to Delphi before function return

Tags: c++, delphi

I want to change size of buffer array in Delphi program if C++ DLL function copies longer array.
Delphi Code:

```
function sendUserAllocatedArray(AllocatedArrayPtr: PAnsiChar; Length: Integer): Integer; cdecl;
external 'DLLlibrary.dll';

var
  myCharPtr : PAnsiChar;
  size : integer;  
  UserAllocatedArray: array[0..10] of AnsiChar;
  arrayPtr: PAnsiChar;
begin
    UserAllocatedArray :=  'test123';
    arrayPtr := UserAllocatedArray;
    size := sendUserAllocatedArray(arrayPtr, Length(UserAllocatedArray));   
end
```

C++ DLL:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int sendUserAllocatedArray(char* data, int length);

int sendUserAllocatedArray(char* data, int length)
{
    char char_array[] = "this array length is more than 10";
    datLength = sizeof(char_array);
    if(datLength < length)
        strcpy_s(data, length, char_array);
    else
        ....;   

    return length;
}
```

So i need to allocate more space if bigger buffer needed before DLL function copy the data to array.
Do i need handler. How can it be done.

Comment: The receiving function is guessing a buffer size - this is pointless, don't do it. The C DLL needs to provide a method that can return the size of buffer required. Often this is implemented using the same function with a branch for the special case of `data` being `null`. `length` should then pass as a pointer instead of by value and `sendUserAllocatedArray` should populate it with the length of buffer it will require. The caller can then allocate an appropriate buffer and call `sendUserAllocatedArray` again, this time with a valid buffer passed in `data`.

Comment: @J... We can't see the code in the `....` section.  But since the function already outputs the copied `length` as a return value, it is possible for it to return the required `length` without changing that parameter to a pointer. The caller can simply compare the returned `length` with the input `length`, and if the returned `length` is larger than retry with a larger buffer. Some Win32 APIs work this way.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, good point - that works too.

Answer (score 5):

Given the code you have shown, the only way to do what you want (without changing the DLL function's signature) is if the DLL function `return`s the required buffer length if the input buffer is too small, eg:

```cpp
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int sendUserAllocatedArray(char* data, int length);

int sendUserAllocatedArray(char* data, int length)
{
    char char_array[] = "this array length is more than 10";
    int datLength = sizeof(char_array);
    if ((data) && (datLength <= length))
        memcpy(data, char_array, length);
    return datLength;
}
```

Then the Delphi code can do this:

```pascal
function sendUserAllocatedArray(AllocatedArrayPtr: PAnsiChar; Length: Integer): Integer; cdecl; external 'DLLlibrary.dll';

var
  myCharPtr : array of AnsiChar;
  size : integer;  
  UserAllocatedArray: array[0..10] of AnsiChar;
  arrayPtr: PAnsiChar;
begin
  UserAllocatedArray := 'test123';
  size := sendUserAllocatedArray(UserAllocatedArray, Length(UserAllocatedArray));
  if size <= Length(UserAllocatedArray) then
  begin
    arrayPtr := UserAllocatedArray;
  end else
  begin
    SetLength(myCharPtr, size);
    arrayPtr := PAnsiChar(myCharPtr);
    StrLCopy(arrayPtr, UserAllocatedArray, size-1);
    size := sendUserAllocatedArray(arrayPtr, size);
  end;
  // use arrayPtr up to size chars as needed...
end;
```

Which can be simplified to this:

```pascal
function sendUserAllocatedArray(AllocatedArrayPtr: PAnsiChar; Length: Integer): Integer; cdecl; external 'DLLlibrary.dll';

var
  size : integer;  
  UserAllocatedArray: array of AnsiChar;
begin
  SetLength(UserAllocatedArray, 10);
  StrLCopy(PAnsiChar(UserAllocatedArray), 'test123', Length(UserAllocatedArray)-1);
  repeat
    size := sendUserAllocatedArray(PAnsiChar(UserAllocatedArray), Length(UserAllocatedArray));
    if size <= Length(UserAllocatedArray) then Break;
    SetLength(UserAllocatedArray, size);
  until False;
  // use UserAllocatedArray up to size chars as needed...
end;
```

Or this:

```pascal
function sendUserAllocatedArray(AllocatedArrayPtr: PAnsiChar; Length: Integer): Integer; cdecl; external 'DLLlibrary.dll';

var
  size : integer;  
  UserAllocatedArray: array of AnsiChar;
begin
  size := sendUserAllocatedArray(nil, 0);
  SetLength(UserAllocatedArray, size);
  StrLCopy(PAnsiChar(UserAllocatedArray), 'test123', size-1);
  size := sendUserAllocatedArray(PAnsiChar(UserAllocatedArray), size);
  // use UserAllocatedArray up to size chars as needed...
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

It is widely used solution in APIs (which fills passed memory array up with contents) to interpret the memory array input parameter NIL value as a mode switch to calculate the necessary memory needs.

This fuction should:

1. Pass the memory needs back as a result.
2. Check whether the memory pointer NIL or not.
3. Check the passed memory array size and throw an exception in the right cases. (Comment : C has NOT exception mechanism! In case of C you must use special return values to inform the caller about the invalid input parameter value / processing errors)
4. Of course, if you call C/C++ DLL function, the call convension must be set. Most of the cases `cdecl`/`stdcall`.

The example code for `C` DLL function:

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TDLLFunction = function ( buffer_ : pointer; memSize_ : integer ) : integer; cdecl;

  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    fDLLFunction : TDLLFunction;

  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function testDLLFunction( mem_ : pchar; memSize_ : integer ) : integer; cdecl;
const
  CONST_text_Viered : array [0..3] of char = '1234';
begin
  result := ( length( CONST_text_Viered ) + 1 )*sizeOf( char );
  if ( mem_ <> NIL ) then
    if ( memSize_ >= result ) then
      strPCopy( mem_, CONST_text_Viered )
    else
      result := -1;
end;


procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  memSize : integer;
  memArray : pchar;
begin
  memSize := fDLLFunction( NIL, 0 );
  getMem( memArray, memSize );
  try
    if ( fDLLFunction( memArray, memSize ) >= 0 ) then
    begin
      // Do some usefull think with memArray
    end else
      showMessage( 'Unsufficient memory error!' );
  finally
    freeMem( memArray );
  end;
end;

procedure TForm3.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fDLLFunction := @testDLLFunction;
end;

end.
```

Example code for `C++` DLL function:

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TDLLFunction = function ( buffer_ : pointer; memSize_ : cardinal ) : cardinal; stdcall;

  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    fDLLFunction : TDLLFunction;

  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

type
  EUnsufficientMemoryError = class ( Exception )
    public 
      constructor Create( currentSize_, minimumSize_ : cardinal );
  end;

constructor EUnsufficientMemoryError.Create( currentSize_, minimumSize_ : cardinal );
begin
  inherited Create( 'Unsufficient memory! Current size: ' + intToStr( currentSize_ ) + ' Minimum size: ' + intToStr( minimumSize_ ) );
end;

function testDLLFunction( mem_ : pchar; memSize_ : cardinal ) : cardinal; stdcall;
const
  CONST_text_Viered : array [0..3] of char = '1234';
begin
  result := ( length( CONST_text_Viered ) + 1 )*sizeOf( char );
  if ( mem_ <> NIL ) then
    if ( memSize_ >= result ) then
      strPCopy( mem_, CONST_text_Viered )
    else
      raise EUnsufficientMemoryError.Create( memSize_, result );
end;


procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  memSize: cardinal;
  memArray : pchar;

begin
  memSize := fDLLFunction( NIL, 0 );
  getMem( memArray, memSize );
  try
    try
      fDLLFunction( memArray, memSize );
      // Do some useful think with memArray
    except
      on e : EUnsufficientMemoryError do
        //...
        ;
    end;
  finally
    freeMem( memArray );
  end;
end;

procedure TForm3.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fDLLFunction := @testDLLFunction;
end;

end.
```